# Add array items based on a value and remove duplicate value in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array in php like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
             [date] => 21/06/2014 
             [total_booking] => 1 
           ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
             [date] => 21/06/2014 
             [total_booking] => 1 
           ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
             [date] => 22/06/2014 
             [total_booking] => 2 
           )
)
```

What i am trying to do is i want to remove duplicate dates and add total_booking of removed date to one unique date.
Eg:

**I have 1 booking in an instance and 2 bookings in other instance on 21/06/2014.
Now I want to add all bookings, in  this case 3 on 21/06/2014.**

Following is my code:

```
$booking_total=0;

$trend_array=array();
$do_not_duplicate=array();
foreach($EM_Bookings as $EM_Booking){
    $booking_date = date_i18n(get_option('dbem_date_format'), $EM_Booking->timestamp);
    $booking_total  = $EM_Booking->get_spaces();
    $do_not_duplicate[]=$booking_date;
    if (in_array($booking_date, $do_not_duplicate)) {
        $do_not_duplicate[]=$booking_date;
        $booking_array=array('date' =>$booking_date,'total_booking'=>$booking_total);
        array_push($trend_array,$booking_array);
    }else{
        // i want to add  $booking_total  to corresponding date
    }

}
```

Comment: Both Lars & Holt gave answers that will work in your specific case, but if the data comes from some kind of database it will be much better to group them in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new array indexed with date, and then recreate your array:

```
$newarray = array () ;
foreach ($EM_Bookings as $EM_Booking) {
    $booking_date = date_i18n(get_option('dbem_date_format'), $EM_Booking->timestamp);
    $booking_total  = $EM_Booking->get_spaces();
    if (array_key_exists($booking_date, $newarray)) {
        $newarray[$booking_date] += $booking_total ; // Add to existing array
    }
    else {
        $newarray[$booking_date] = $booking_total ; // Create new
    }
}
```

Here, `newarray` looks like:

```
Array (
    [21/06/2014] => 2,
    [22/06/2014] => 2
)
```

So you can easily create the array you want, like so:

```
$finalarray = array () ;
foreach ($newarray as $date => $booking) {
    $finalarray[] = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'total_booking' => $booking
    ) ;
}
```

Comment: That's what me said ;)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want the number of bookings per day, no?

```
$data = array([...]);

$days = array();

foreach($data as $day => $num) {
    if(!isset($days[$day])) {
        $days[$day] = 0;
    }

    $days[$day] += $num;
}
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
$unique = array();
foreach($EM_Bookings as $booking){
    $date = $booking['date'];
    if(!key_exists($date, $unique)){
            $unique[$date] = $booking['total_booking'];
    }else{  
            $unique[$date] += $booking['total_booking'];
    }
}

/*
 print_r($unique); 

 Array
(
[21/06/2014] => 2
[22/06/2014] => 2
)

*/
```